# list of dict, how to fill out information later

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iterator

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
mylist=[
    {
        'name':None,
        'Id':sys.argv[1]
    },{
        'name':None,
        'Id':sys.argv[2]
    },{
        'name':None,
        'Id':sys.argv[3]
    }
]
```

I later invoke a subprocess and process it output, I want to put the output in 'name' value field. after I invoke the command I endup with a list of all lines and I read the lines like this

```
for line in content:
    if line.startswith('some_identifier'):
        line.strip('\n')
        #put the line into an unused 'name' value field
```

later I want to generate a login command that is run by the OS like so:

```
for info in mylist
    subprocess.check_output(['iscsicli.exe', 'LoginTarget', info['name'], 'T', portalip, portalport, '*', info['Id'], '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'])
```

so what I want to do is be able to put the line read in the second code snippet in the an unused 'name' slot in mylist

Comment: When do you ever use `myList`?

Comment: I later generate some information based on the info in the list. I iterate over it and generate the content.

Comment: But in what way do you even relate the existing structure to the code?

Comment: the structure is not as important, what ID is linked to what name doesn`t matter to me but it is important that the 3 different id`s are used. It is for a login script for iSCSI targets. I am updating my question so it is more clear

Comment: I see some statements here, but what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in content:
    if line.startswith('some_identifier'):
        line.strip('\n')
        #put the line into an unused 'name' value field
        for dict in mylist:
            if dict['name'] == None:
                dict['name'] = line
                break
```